# Authorize roles via database

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am building an ASP.net MVC 4 application.

In the past I have used the [Authorize] attribute to authorize users according to their role(s).

However, I now need to a more flexible solution where role authorization can be changed by altering the database rather than changing the source code.

Can anyone recommend a suitable way to do this?

I have looked into overriding the OnAuthorize method but apparently this is not recommended due to issues with output caching.

Comment: What do you mean by *altering the database*? Could you clarify with a concrete example?

Comment: By altering the database I mean updating a mapping table  that maps (allowed) roles to actions/controllers

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22724798/mvc-role-authorization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this, we have been using this in our application

```
[AttributeUsageAttribute
        (AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Struct |
        AttributeTargets.Constructor | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = false)]
    public class RequirePermissionsAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
// Use inbuilt methods
```

//OnAuthorization
//HandleUnauthorizedRequest
//OnCacheAuthorization
    }

```
        [RequirePermissions(PermissionItems.ViewThisPage)]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your requirement correctly, but you could have two levels of roles, with a data model something like:

```
User -in-> Role -has-> Permission
```

With m-n relationships between Users and Roles, and between Roles and Permissions.

If you do this, your permissions can be quite fine-grained and stable, while roles can be coarse-grained and flexibly mapped to sets of permissions.

One way to implement this is to simply write a custom [RoleProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.aspx) that does the join Users-Roles-Permissions and returns the permissions as application roles.

If you do this, you can use the standard `Authorize` attribute, specifying one of your fine-grained permission names rather than a coarse-grained role name, e.g.:

```
[Authorize(Permissions.ViewCustomers)]
```