# MVC Role Authorization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, authorization

I am trying to implement a role authorization mechanism which checks the roles of the current logged in user, if the user is in the right role, he/she is allowed, else display error view.

The problem is that when the user tries to access the below method in the controller, he does get into the RoleAuthorizationAttribute class and gets verfied but then the method in the controller is not executed.

Note : the user has the Client role

Controller method

```
[RoleAuthorization(Roles = "Client, Adminsitrator")]
    public ActionResult addToCart(int ProductID, string Quantity)
    {
        tempShoppingCart t = new tempShoppingCart();
        t.ProductID = ProductID;
        t.Username = User.Identity.Name;
        t.Quantity = Convert.ToInt16(Quantity);

        new OrdersService.OrdersClient().addToCart(t);
        ViewData["numberOfItemsInShoppingCart"] = new OrdersService.OrdersClient().getNoOfItemsInShoppingCart(User.Identity.Name);
        ViewData["totalPriceInSC"] = new OrdersService.OrdersClient().getTotalPriceOfItemsInSC(User.Identity.Name);
        return PartialView("quickShoppingCart", "Orders");
    }
```

Role Authentication class

```
[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.All,AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class RoleAuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {


        List<String> requiredRoles = Roles.Split(Convert.ToChar(",")).ToList();

        List<Role> allRoles = new UsersService.UsersClient().GetUserRoles(filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name).ToList();


        bool Match = false;

        foreach (String s in requiredRoles)
        {
            foreach (Role r in allRoles)
            {
                string rName = r.RoleName.Trim().ToString();
                string sName = s.Trim();
                if (rName == sName)
                {
                    Match = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!Match)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "AccessDenied" };
        }

        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

    }
}
```

Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong

Comment: care to tell why the downvote please ? IM still new to mvc

Comment: If you do [Authorize(Roles = "Client, Adminsitrator")], that should do what you need.

Comment: isnt that for MVC4? Im using MVC3

Comment: It should work with even previous versions, it's been there for a while.

Comment: Its not working, its giving me the login page but I am logged in :/

Comment: That'd mean you do not have those particular roles. Please debug and see the error.

Comment: How is it checking against my database ? in the authorizeattribute class, there is nothing I could see that is checking?

Comment: Did you add breakpoint to OnAuthorization() method and check? What happens there?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since I had the roles of the users in the database I had to check against the database so I included this method in the global.asax

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        if (Context.User != null)
        {
            IEnumerable<Role> roles = new UsersService.UsersClient().GetUserRoles(
                                                    Context.User.Identity.Name);


            string[] rolesArray = new string[roles.Count()];
            for (int i = 0; i < roles.Count(); i++)
            {
                rolesArray[i] = roles.ElementAt(i).RoleName;
            }

            GenericPrincipal gp = new GenericPrincipal(Context.User.Identity, rolesArray);
            Context.User = gp;
        }
    }
```

Then I could use the normal

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Client, Administrator")]
```

On top of the actionResult methods in the controllers

This worked.

Comment: some people store user roles in auth cookie or owin cookie in asp.net mvc5. so if the situation is like that then how can i extract role from auth cookie or owin cookie.......any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: @MonojitSarkar If I understood you right, Instead of getting the list of roles from the database, get them from the cookie/s. Search on how to get cookies in global.asax, then populate the rolesArray as in my example

Answer (score 2):

Your original code was close, but the problem lies here:

```
base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
```

Unconditionally calling the base class means you are requiring the decorated roles to be found in BOTH the UsersService and the built-in Role provider. If the role provider isn't configured to return the same set of roles (which they wouldn't if the default AuthorizeAttribute isn't sufficient for you) then this will obviously result in the Authorization test always returning false.

Instead you could add a separate property to the derived Attribute such as

```
public string RemoteRoles { get; set; }
```

and replace

```
 List<String> requiredRoles = Roles.Split(Convert.ToChar(",")).ToList();
```

with:

```
 List<String> requiredRoles = RemoteRoles.Split(Convert.ToChar(",")).ToList();
```

And decorate your controller like such:

```
[RoleAuthorization (RemoteRoles = "Client, Administrator")]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MVC 5 you have to enable lazy loading in your DbContext by putting the following line in your DbContext initialisation.

```
this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
```

In MVC 5 default project you'll add it to ApplicationDbContext.cs file.

I'm not sure if this is particular to MVC 5, to Identity 2.0, or affect other versions. I'm using this setup and enabling lazy loading make all the default role schema works. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/20433316/2401947 for more info.

Additionally, if you're using ASP.NET Identity 2.0 default permission schema, you don't have to implement Application_AuthenticateRequest as Darren mentioned. But if you're using custom authorisation tables, then you have to implement it as well.